# What is the probability that you will see a 5 on the die before you see tails on the coin?

Tags: probability

Suppose you alternate between throwing a normal six-sided fair die and tossing a fair
coin. You start by throwing the die. What is the probability that you will see a 5 on
the die before you see tails on the coin?

I am finding hard to understand the question.
Can anyone tell me the desired outcomes for it?
Based on my understanding,

5T, 5H5T, 6H5T ,....
Is the above valid desired outcomes ?

Comment: Well, not really.  All those sequences would stop at the first $5$.  the problem asks "in the given game, what is the probability that you see a $5$ at some point before you see a $T$?"  It is not required that the $T$ immediately follow the $5$.  thus the sequence $6H3H4T$ is a fail, since $T$ came before we saw a $5$.

Comment: Hi,Can you please tell me why this sequence is not valid ? 6H5HT . In this sequence, 5 appeared before T.

Comment: I throw a die. If I get 5, I win and the game ends ; if not, you throw a coin ; if you get 'Tail', you win and the game ends. And we repeat this until I win or you win.

Comment: As I said, the game would have ended at the first $5$.  $6H5$ is already a success.  There is no point in continuing the sequence past the first $5$ or $T$.  Also, your sequence has two coin tosses in a row, counter the rules of the game.

Comment: Hi, I could understand that there is no point in continuing the sequence after the first T , since we are not going to get our desired outcome (5 before T). But, if i get a 5, then in the next toss, I may get a head right ? I think I am not understanding the question properly.

Comment: 5 before T does not means that we should have a 5 just before a T.  It means : which one appears first , 5 or T ?  Look at my previous comment.

Comment: I explained the rules in my first comment.  You are just looking for a $5$ or a $T$, it makes no difference what comes after (or if you just stop).

Comment: You can simulate the game. Get a fair die and a coin and just try it, to get a feel for the answer.

Comment: This problem can be solved recursively. Once you have rolled something other than a 5 followed by heads, you are in exactly the same place you started. So the probability $P(5BT)$ of rolling a 5 before a $T$ can be expressed as the probability of rolling a 5 plus the probability of rolling a non-5 times the probability of flipping an $H$ times $P(5BT)$. This can be solved for $P(5BT)$ to yield $P(5BT) = 2/7$. A simple simulation of this game agrees with this result.